# HTML <video> audio does not play on iPad after Add to Homescreen

Tags: html, audio, video

This one has me stumped. I have an HTML web app with MP4 video embedded using the HTML5  tag. Everything seems to work fine in a browser, both desktop and iPad.  But when I use the Add to Home Screen button to save a shortcut, I no longer get audio with my video.

Any ideas?

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

<video id="videoContent" controls="true" width="400" height="225" preload="auto"><source src="video.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I have this issue on a customers device